# One computer cannot access port from another on the same same network

Tags: networking, firewall, linux-networking, port, mqtt

I have two servers with relatively fresh installs of CentOS 9 Stream on the same network.  I can ping and ssh between them so can prove basic connectivity. serverA AFAIK has port 1883 (mqtt) open and I have a simple python test server listening.  But when I try to access port 1883 from serverB I get Connection refused.

```
[serverA]$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp1s0f1
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client mqtt ssh
  ports: 1883/tcp 9001/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

[serverA]$ sudo netstat -tunlp
    ...
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1497041/python
    ...
```

_

```
[serverB]$ curl -g -6 "http://[<<serverA ipv6>>]:1883"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <<serverA ipv6>> port 1883: Connection refused

[serverB]$ nc -z -v -w5 <<serverA ipv6>> 1883
Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

From initial research on the error I can check off:

- According to Firewalld port 1883 is open on serverA (explicitly and through mqtt service)
- serverA is actively listening on 0 0.0.0.0:1883 (not 127.0.0.1 etc)
- AFAIK there's no extra firewall hardware affecting traffic between the two servers

What else can I test? Not sure if iptables has any bearing here since I'm using Firewalld

**EDIT AND MORE CONTEXT:**

So I documented how I solved this below, but wanted to give some context which might be helpful to future travelers.

I was trying to get comms to a mosquitto mqtt broker working which was running via docker compose.  To take one variable out of the equation I used a simple test python server directly from the OS.  The real issue was this line in mosquitto.conf:

```
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
```

The trailing 0.0.0.0 was inadvertently setting mosquitto to only listen on ipv4.  Even though there's no specific info about this in the Listener section of the mosquitto docs the socket_domain section states this:
https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

> If you want support for both IPv4 and IPv6, then do not use the
> socket_domain option.

So all I had to do was just change the line to:

```
listener 1883
```

and mosquitto magically started listening on ipv4 and ipv6

Answer (score 0):

OK this me not knowing enough about ipv6 v ipv4.  I noticed that port 22 worked but 1883 didn't:

```
[serverB]$ nmap -6 -Pn -p 1883 <<serverA ipv6>>
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1883/tcp closed mqtt

[serverB]$ nmap -6 -Pn -p 22 <<serverA ipv6>>
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

So then I looked at the listening ports on serverA and noticed that 1883 was listed as tcp and 22 tcp6:

```
[serverA]$ sudo netstat -tunlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10077/python
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1602/sshd: /usr/sbi
...
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1602/sshd: /usr/sbi
...
```

So I changed my test server script to listen on tcp ipv6.
Old ipv4 only server test script:

```
import socket

# Create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Define the port on which you want to connect
port = 1883

# Bind to the port
s.bind(('', port))

# Put the socket into listening mode
s.listen(5)
print('Socket is listening')

# A forever loop until we interrupt it or an error occurs
while True:
    # Establish connection with client
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got connection from', addr)

    # Send a thank you message to the client
    c.send(b'Thank you for connecting')

    # Close the connection with the client
    c.close()
```

New ipv6 server script:

```
import socket

# Create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Define the port on which you want to connect
port = 1883

# Bind to the port
s.bind(('::', port))

# Put the socket into listening mode
s.listen(5)
print('Socket is listening')

# A forever loop until we interrupt it or an error occurs
while True:
    # Establish connection with client
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got connection from', addr)

    # Send a thank you message to the client
    c.send(b'Thank you for connecting')

    # Close the connection with the client
    c.close()
```

I now have a process listening on port 1883 using ipv6:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN      10177/python
```

And I can connect using port 1883 from serverB to serverA